# How to reuse token bewteen magento and other jwt based platforms

Tags: token

I am using a customised login where token is generated from AWS Cognito. i am also adding some jwt claims to make the token usable with integration such as apollo .i want to use the same token for customer to access magento instead of creating separate token using username and password.

i want to use token for rest api and also i need customer-token

Is there any way to achieve this? am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I am very happy if I can solve the problem for you.

Reusing tokens between Magento and other JWT-based platforms is an efficient way to manage authentication across multiple systems. This process can be used to securely authenticate a user’s identity, ensuring that the right person has access to the right resources.

The first step in reusing tokens between Magento and another JWT-based platform is setting up a shared secret key on each system which will be used when signing or verifying token payloads. Once this is done, users can generate their unique token on either system by providing their credentials along with any additional information needed for authorization purposes such as roles or permissions associated with them on each platform separately. The generated token should then be stored securely to use later when authenticating requests from either side of the connection without having users enter credentials again every time they need access rights granted by one of these two systems.

Finally, once all necessary data has been provided, developers can utilize existing APIs available within both platforms to make sure that when using the same valid JWT issued from one source, it also works seamlessly across different services connected through them as well. This allows us to save time while maintaining high-security standards at the same time since no extra steps like entering passwords manually would have been required during the login process anymore after the initial setup phase was completed successfully beforehand.

If you have any questions, contact us on the site **IdeaInYou**

Have a good day.